# Networking Topology Design

Tags: networking

currently I have two network topology designs.

First one is

One router and then that router connect to switch A, then switch B will connected to switch A. Then APs are connect to both Switch A and B.

Second one is

One router and then that router will connect to Switch A, then Switch B and C will be connected to Switch A, then all the APs will be connected to B and C.

Which one is better and why?

Comment: Why do you need 2 switches? You can easily just have Router1, Switch A and connect AP's. It's cheaper and more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The additional switch in topology 2 does not help anything, so it's not necessary. You can have APs connected to both A and B with no problem, even if topology is R-A-B.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your requirement and physical network setup. If you only need to cover one area then the first one is better, even with only one switch.

But if you need to cover let's say two areas then the number two is better because if you need to replace, maintain or troubleshoot one area, the other one can still work and serve your client.